# Using Three.js in Node (CommonJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js

When looking into the [example source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_postprocessing.html#L19) of the Threejs.org [examples](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene) we see there is direct editing of the global Three object when you want to implement a module. Additionally, those examples have a ton of tiny libs/objects/modules that do not seem to be part of any npm package.

How can we leverage these libs (eg. CodeShader.js) in our CommonJS style node code?

Comment: Where did you find the CodeShader.js? You just need the three.js lib. Maybe you want also some others, but they are not part of the three.js lib.